# AVL Tree Deletion causing program to crash

Tags: c, visual-studio, access-violation, avl-tree

So I have code for a Binary Search Tree in C that works fine for me. However when I add code for a BST deletion, my program will crash during that deletion.

It gives me an error saying ***Access violation reading location 0x00000000.***

I think this is something to do with passing NULL pointers, or something. Maybe I read that somewhere, or maybe that's completely wrong and I'm silly.

Anyway, here is my code for my AVL deletion. If you could help me in getting my program working and help me understand what I did wrong, I'd be very grateful. I'll also include my function for finding the minimum node, because I feel as if it may be the culprit.

```
AVL min_node(AVL self)
{
    /*  A AVL node to keep track of the current node. */
    AVL current = self;


    /*  This loop finds the minimum node, by traversing the tree until the leftmost node is discovered. */
    while (!empty_tree(current))
    {
        current = current->left;
    }

    /*  Returns the tree.   */
    return current;
}



AVL delete(AVL self, long id)
{

    if (self != NULL)
    {
        if (id == self->student_id)
        {
            if (self->left != NULL)
            {
                AVL successor = min_node(self->right);
                self->student_id = successor->student_id;
                self->right = delete(self->right, self->student_id);
            }
            else
            {
                AVL to_free = self;
                if (self->left)
                {
                    self = self->left;
                }
                else
                {
                    self = self->right;
                }
                free(to_free);
            }
        }
        else if (id < self->student_id)
        {
            self->left = delete(self->left, id);
        }
        else
        {
            self->right = delete(self->right, id);
        }
    }

    /*NEW SHIT*/
    int balance = getBalance(self);

    //Left Left Case
    if (balance > 1 && getBalance(self->left) >= 0)
    {
        return rotateRight(self);
    }
    //Left Right Case
    if (balance > 1 && getBalance(self->left) < 0)
    {
        self->left = leftRotate(self->left);
        return rotateRight(self);
    }
    //Right Right Case
    if (balance < -1 && getBalance(self->right) <= 0)
    {
        return leftRotate(self);
    }
    //Right Left Case
    if (balance < -1 && getBalance(self->right) > 0)
    {
        self->right = rotateRight(self->right);
        return leftRotate(self);
    }

    return self;
}
```

**UPDATE:** So it seems to be crashing on one of two lines in delete function:

```
self->student_id = successor->student_id;
```

OR

```
AVL successor = min_node(self->right);
```

**EDIT 2:** Upon request, I've included my entire avl.c file.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "avl.h"

bool names_match(char* name_one, char* name_two)
{
    if (strcmp(name_one, name_two) == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool empty_tree(AVL self)
{
    if (self == NULL)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}


AVL leftRotate(AVL self)
{
    AVL y = self->right;
    AVL T2 = y->left;

    y->left = self;
    self->right = T2;

    return y;
}

AVL rotateRight(AVL self)
{
    AVL x = self->left;
    AVL T2 = x->right;

    x->right = self;
    self->left = T2;

    return x;
}

int getBalance(AVL node)
{
    if (node == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return height(node->left) - height(node->right);
}


AVL insert(AVL self, long id)
{
    if (self == NULL)
    {
        self = (AVL)malloc(sizeof(struct avlNode));
        self->student_id = id;
        self->left = self->right = NULL;
    }
    else if (id < self->student_id)
    {
        self->left = insert(self->left, id);
    }
    else if (id > self->student_id)
    {
        self->right = insert(self->right, id);
    }


    /*NEW SHIT*/
    int balance = getBalance(self);

    //Left Left Case
    if (balance > 1 && id < self->left->student_id)
    {
        return rotateRight(self);
    }
    //Right Right Case
    if (balance < -1 && id > self->right->student_id)
    {
        return leftRotate(self);
    }
    //Left Right Case
    if (balance > 1 && id > self->left->student_id)
    {
        self->left = leftRotate(self->left);
        return rotateRight(self);
    }
    //Right Left Case
    if (balance < -1 && id < self->right->student_id)
    {
        self->right = rotateRight(self->right);
        return leftRotate(self);
    }

    //Return unchanged pointer (i dunno why. could probably be void)
    return self;
}

/*  === AVL MINIMUM NODE ===
Finds the minimum node in a AVL.
*/
AVL min_node(AVL self)
{
    /*  A AVL node to keep track of the current node. */
    AVL current = self;

    /*  This loop finds the minimum node, by traversing the tree until the leftmost node is discovered. */
    while (!empty_tree(current->left))
    {
        current = current->left;
    }

    /*  Returns the tree.   */
    return current;
}



AVL delete(AVL self, long id)
{
    if (self != NULL)
    {
        if (id == self->student_id)
        {
            if (self->left != NULL)
            {
                AVL successor = min_node(self->right);
                self->student_id = successor->student_id;
                self->right = delete(self->right, self->student_id);
            }
            else
            {
                AVL to_free = self;
                if (self->left)
                {
                    self = self->left;
                }
                else
                {
                    self = self->right;
                }
                free(to_free);
            }
        }
        else if (id < self->student_id)
        {
            self->left = delete(self->left, id);
        }
        else
        {
            self->right = delete(self->right, id);
        }
    }

    /*NEW SHIT*/
    if (self == NULL)
    {
        return self; //ADDED TODAY
    }

    int balance = getBalance(self);

    //Left Left Case
    if (balance > 1 && getBalance(self->left) >= 0)
    {
        return rotateRight(self);
    }
    //Left Right Case
    if (balance > 1 && getBalance(self->left) < 0)
    {
        self->left = leftRotate(self->left);
        return rotateRight(self);
    }
    //Right Right Case
    if (balance < -1 && getBalance(self->right) <= 0)
    {
        return leftRotate(self);
    }
    //Right Left Case
    if (balance < -1 && getBalance(self->right) > 0)
    {
        self->right = rotateRight(self->right);
        return leftRotate(self);
    }

    return self;
}

/*  === AVL NODE COUNT ===
Counts the number of nodes in the AVL.
*/
int number_of_nodes(AVL self)
{
    /*  If the tree is empty, return a count of 0 nodes.    */
    if (empty_tree(self))
    {
        return(0);
    }
    /*  If the tree is not empty, but its left and right nodes are, return a count of 1 node.   */
    else if (empty_tree(self->left) && empty_tree(self->right))
    {
        return(1);
    }

    /*  If the tree is not empty, and its left and right nodes are also not empty, run this function recursively in the left and right nodes.   */
    else
    {
        return(1 + (number_of_nodes(self->left) + number_of_nodes(self->right)));
    }

}

/*  === AVL HEIGHT ===
Returns the total height of a AVL.
*/
int height(AVL self)
{
    /*  If the tree is empty, return a count of 0 nodes.    */
    if (empty_tree(self))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    /*  If the tree is not empty, run this fucntion recursively on the left and right branches, returning the max of the two.   */
    else
    {
        return 1 + max(height(self->left), height(self->right));
    }
}



/*  === PRINT AVL ===
Prints a AVL in pre-order.
*/
void print_pre_order(AVL self)
{

    /*  If the tree isn't empty, print the node's ID and then run this function recursively on the left and then the right nodes,
    to print pre order. */
    if (!empty_tree(self))
    {
        printf("%d", self->student_id);
        printf("\n");
        print_pre_order(self->left);
        print_pre_order(self->right);

    }
}

/*  === SEARCH AVL ===
Searches a AVL for a particular node.
*/
bool searchTree(AVL self, long id)
{
    if (!empty_tree(self))
    {
        /*  If the node's ID matches the input ID, return true. */
        if (self->student_id == id)
        {
            return true;
        }

        /*  If the node's ID doesn't match the input ID, run this function recurseively on the appropriate node.    */
        else
        {
            if (self->student_id > id)
            {
                return searchTree(self->left, id);
            }
            else if (self->student_id < id)
            {
                return searchTree(self->right, id);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void destroy_tree(AVL self)
{
    /*  If the tree is not empty, free each node in the tree  by running this function recursively on the left and right branches.  */
    if (!empty_tree(self))
    {
        destroy_tree(self->left);
        destroy_tree(self->right);
        free(self);
    }
}
```

**EDIT 3:** Interesting development. The AVL tree being used are actually in a linked list, with each node containing an AVL tree. Now I've come to realise (through lots of testing) that a node on the AVL tree can be deleted, *IF* its the first one that's been built. Very interesting, and even more annoying.

Comment: This is a **perfect** opportunity to use a debugger ;)

Comment: I'm using the debugger. That's how I know my program comes to a problem at delete, and the minimum node function.

Comment: Then what prevents you from narrowing your problem to a specific command and see what happens?

Comment: So what is the line that triggers the access violation? The debugger should give you that, and it seems unnecessary to ask strangers to try to find this line by eye.

Comment: Sorry, it's this line I believe:
_AVL successor = min_node(self->right);_

Comment: I updated my original post with an update to the crashing lines.

Comment: You should step through with the debugger and pinpoint the exact line that triggers the error. Do this a couple times, observing how variables change, and you'll probably figure it out. As it stands, we're shooting in the dark and few are likely to put in the effort to untangle the problem for you. This is a perfect example of what a debugger is for and it will teach you an important skill.

Comment: I see no `main()`, I see no `#include`, I see no `AVL` structure definition. I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the 'self->right' which you are passing to the function.  If 'self' is a pointer which I am assuming it is then in my opinion you should pass the 'address' of the 'self' like so '&(self->right)' and the current should be assigned the value of the '&self' like so 'current = *self'.  Then I think it could work.
I think I can correct with what I am saying if am I provided with the entire code but I think you get the gist

Comment: Tried your suggestion. Didn't work, unfortunately. The thing that irritates me is that it all works fine with my Binary Search Tree. I just can't figure out why it crashes with the extra AVL code.

Comment: Sure, I've added it to the main post.